# Altair showing error on graphs and vega-lite itself isn't

Tags: python, altair, vega-lite

I have some vega-lite specifications in a csv that I want to load into python and show using altair. I am loading them in as strings, converting to json, and then using altair to display them, which is working for most of the speifications, but some of them are giving an error and I am not sure why. Below is the code for a spec that gives the error. The error it gives is ValueError: Only chart objects can be used in RepeatChart.

```
spec_str= '''{"$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v3.json", "data": {"url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nlvcorpus/nlvcorpus.github.io/main/datasets/movies.csv"}, "mark": {"type": "bar", "tooltip": null}, "encoding": {"column": {"field": "Content Rating", "type": "ordinal"}, "x": {"field": "Creative Type", "scale": {"rangeStep": 15}, "type": "nominal", "axis": {"title": "", "labels": false, "ticks": false}}, "y": {"aggregate": "mean", "field": "Production Budget", "type": "quantitative", "axis": {"title": "AVG (Production Budget)", "format": "~s"}}, "color": {"field": "Creative Type", "type": "nominal"}}}'''
jsonspec = json.loads(spec_str)
chart = alt.Chart.from_dict(jsonspec, validate=False)
```

When I put this exact same specification into https://vega.github.io/editor/#/edited, the chart renders just fine. Is there any way to fix this, or another way to load vega-lite specifications into python?

EDIT:

Here is a link to the spec that works. [Spec](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAMyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUAwBOgtBmx5CBbUgDu1OoyYMIcbVDmY4szJUcICswcUfactl4+fgEQlvTMrBzINLIEqup2mBAECGzENHBhUBDEIAC+SsjaANZooJgAnjhw+kxI2oogmGxsgpg0OGiyDIKChSAujsqxZOUgjoIMCPKaIABmmYLK+gDCTi6YAAQASmqjTVU1+mzaI7JIegMAHuOLcMtr2nD7pFsAKtW1StCXtXOmWRkOAAZWcXVQAEYAKwDI7-ECyNgIWKXJpIa40CDjDqYQQIpqCJBMB7Y1DzS52JQdKAlMkUwR2fIDSrjJBkMjPCjOfQIF7yJT3R7oAAK2jYygYUA6ci2ACEGMpgZhDl99ABHBhIVx0V7fEAYrE4uj4-QAQQAagBxLYACjFEqlMtk8sVyoAlE15qdkCr0AA-bHMpSTU53JYrdCrZ56j5q6lq9BIlEXK7MoA)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The link you provided works only for you - vega editor is saving the latest version of the code you edited in your browser's localStorage and when you access the site it's using that code as a starting point. You may try accessing the link from another browser on your machine to see what others are seeing. If you intend to share your vega lite json, please use the "Share" menu on top of vega lite editor - it will create a huge URL that you can hide on your post using a [markdown link](https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#links) or even a url shortener.

Answer (score 0):

The `rangeStep` parameter was deprecated a long time ago (see https://altair-viz.github.io/releases/changes.html#id12). If you delete that from your specification, it will render:

```py
import altair as alt

alt.Chart.from_dict({
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v3.json",
  "data": {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nlvcorpus/nlvcorpus.github.io/main/datasets/movies.csv"
  },
  "mark": {"type": "bar", "tooltip": None},
  "encoding": {
    "column": {"field": "Content Rating", "type": "ordinal"},
    "x": {
      "field": "Creative Type",
      "type": "nominal",
      "axis": {"title": "", "labels": False, "ticks": False}
    },
    "y": {
      "aggregate": "mean",
      "field": "Production Budget",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "axis": {"title": "AVG (Production Budget)", "format": "~s"}
    },
    "color": {"field": "Creative Type", "type": "nominal"}
  }
})
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `chart.configure_view(step=rangeStep)` as mentioned in the changelog above.